# Any array to Character array

Tags: arrays, swift, converters

I already tried this:

```
var newArray = oldArray.map
    {
        Character($0)
}
```

where oldArray is an array with type [Any]. However, I get an error when I insert that code. Is there another option?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Character'  with an argument list of type ' ((Any))'"

Comment: What is `oldArray` an array *of?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Any` cannot be directly converted to `Character`, but needs to first be casted to `String` (from which it is a simple task to convert (the first character in the string) to `Character`:

```
let arr: [Any] = ["k", "n"]
let newArr = arr.flatMap { ($0 as? String)?.characters.first }
print(newArr, type(of: newArr)) // ["k", "n"] Array<Character>
```

Answer (score 0):

If oldArray contains object of type Character:

```
var oldArray:[Any] = []
....
var newArray = oldArray.map {
        $0 as! Character
}
```

in this way it compiles, but you can get runtime exception accordin to the value stored in oldArray.

Comment: This will blow up spectacularly if the elements in `oldArray` aren't `Character`s (or can't be converted to `Character`s). And if they *are* already `Character`s, then there's no need for them to be converted.

Comment: yes but it compiles, an no error are generated by the compiler. The user had an error at compile time.

Comment: Ok, thank you no errors now! However, I wanted to use this code furthermore in my code. This code worked with an other array, but now I get the error: 'Value of type '[Character]' has no member 'character'". This is my line of code: let decoded = String(newArray.characters.map({ decode[$0] ?? $0 })) can you answer this or should I make another thread? Thank you anyway!

Comment: Edit: I do get a runtime error when executing this code:Thread 1: signal SIGABRT... lines below are saying this: Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x1003e4a18) to 'Swift.Character' (0x1003de490).
2016-11-02 17:02:40.567080 test[844:164055] Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String' (0x1003e4a18) to 'Swift.Character' (0x1003de490).

Comment: A String cannot be cast to Character. Your treating a String like a Character and you cannot do that